# Laptop charger voltage

Tags: laptop, charging, voltage

I bought a laptop from the US. Now the part that connects from the power brick to the wall socket says 7A 125V.

Unfortunately, the end that goes into the wall socket does not fit. So I replaced the part that connects from the power brick to the wall socket with a 2.5A 250V.

The part is a 3prong cable.

Input on power brick says 100~240V*1.4A 50~60Hz

Is this okay?

Comment: What does the brick say?

Comment: "Unfortunately" <- we'll see about that when you tell us the PSU-specs ;-)

Comment: added info @flolilolilo

Comment: It's a good job the plug didn't fit your wall socket. Plugging a US-only device into the wall in Europe will produce a small bang & flash... & then never work again, even after you replace all the fuses & power-trips :/ Once you have your input voltage correct, then what we need to know is what the **output** details were on the original PSU. Volts, Amps & Polarity. Take a picture if you're not sure & post it to your question.

Comment: @Sam well, there's your answer. If your power outlet outputs an electric potential between 100 and 240 Volts, then it will work perfectly well. *AFAIK, PSUs that support 100-240V should run worldwide.*